# CPP Windows string conversions confusion CStringA and LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, string, windows

I need to use WinAPI function to restart a windows service, I am not familiar with strings in C++.

My function receive as parameter: `const CStringA& serviceName`:

```
bool MyClassName::RestartServer(const CStringA& serviceName)
```

When I obtain SC Handle via `OpenService(..)` I need to provide type `LPCWSTR` :

```
SC_HANDLE SHandle = OpenService(hSCManager, LPCWSTR serviceNameAsWideString, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
```

How do I convert `CStringA` to `LPCWSTR`?

I tried to following:

1. `CA2W(serviceName, CP_UTF8);`
2. `CString str("MyServiceName"); CStringW strw(str); LPCWSTR ptr = strw;`

Both did not work properly, they compiled, but when I tried to execute the code.
It failed to `OpenService()`.
What worked:

3. `LPCWSTR newString = serviceName.AllocSysString();`

What am I missing here? Why 1 and 2 did not work? Why 3 worked?

How do I properly deallocate newString?

Comment: You should *not* specify `CStringA`. You should use `CString` which will select the `A` or `W` version based on compiler settings (just like you are not specifying `OpenServiceW`).

Comment: Thanks for tip I receive CStringA as a tabu that i cannit change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code requires a conversion because you are calling the `TCHAR`-based `OpenService()` macro, which maps to either `OpenServiceW()` or `OpenServiceA()` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined:

```c
__checkReturn
WINADVAPI
SC_HANDLE
WINAPI
OpenServiceA(
    __in            SC_HANDLE               hSCManager,
    __in            LPCSTR                lpServiceName,
    __in            DWORD                   dwDesiredAccess
    );
__checkReturn
WINADVAPI
SC_HANDLE
WINAPI
OpenServiceW(
    __in            SC_HANDLE               hSCManager,
    __in            LPCWSTR                lpServiceName,
    __in            DWORD                   dwDesiredAccess
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define OpenService  OpenServiceW
#else
#define OpenService  OpenServiceA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

In your case, `UNICODE` is clearly being defined in your project, so your code is really calling `OpenServiceW()`, which is why it expects an `LPCWSTR` as input.

Your `RestartServer()` method takes a `CStringA` (`char`-based ANSI) string as input, so you should use `OpenServiceA()` explicitly to match the same character type, no conversion needed:

```cpp
bool MyClassName::RestartServer(const CStringA& serviceName)
{
    ...
    SC_HANDLE SHandle = OpenServiceA(hSCManager, serviceName, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, if you are going to continue using `TCHAR`-based functionality in your code <sup>1</sup>, then you should change your `RestartServer()` method to take a `CString` instead of a `CStringA` so it adopts the same ANSI/Unicode mapping that `OpenService()` does (and other `TCHAR`-based functions do), again avoiding a conversion:

<sup>1: which you should not do, since there is rarely a need to ever write code for Win9x/ME nowadays. Windows has been a Unicode-based OS since NT4.</sup>

```cpp
bool MyClassName::RestartServer(const CString& serviceName)
```

If that is not an option for you, then `CA2W()` will work just fine:

```cpp
bool MyClassName::RestartServer(const CStringA& serviceName)
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    ...
    SC_HANDLE SHandle = OpenService(hSCManager, ATL::CA2W(serviceName), SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    ...
}
```

Though, you might consider just using `CString` internally and let it handle a conversion if needed:

```cpp
bool MyClassName::RestartServer(const CStringA& serviceName)
{
    ...
    SC_HANDLE SHandle = OpenService(hSCManager, CString(serviceName), SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    ...
}
```

Or, make the code conditional:

```cpp
bool MyClassName::RestartServer(const CStringA& serviceName)
{
    ...
    SC_HANDLE SHandle = OpenService(hSCManager,
        #ifdef UNICODE
        CStringW(serviceName)
        #else
        serviceName
        #endif
        , SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great answer - exactly what I wanted, to get high level  picture of whats going on. The issue is that i get CStringA as a fact I cannot change, so cast is required.

Answer (score 2):

`CStringA` and `CStringW` have constructors taking both `const char*` and `const wchar_t*` C strings.

Write following:

```
CStringW serviceNameW( serviceName );
```

About `AllocSysString`, it creates a copy in BSTR, they’re more complex than C strings, they’re null-terminated too but they also have length at negative offset. If you want to do manual memory management, call `SysFreeString` on the pointer. Or if you want BSTR but don’t want manual memory management, use `CComBSTR` class.